# Не добавляются товары в БД

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

При вводе товара в БД появляются пустые поля (кроме первичного ключа).

В чем ошибка?

*add2cat.php*:

```
<?
require "secure/session.inc.php";
require "../inc/db.inc.php";
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Форма добавления товара в каталог</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="save2cat.php" method="post">
        <p>Название: <input type="text" name="title" size="100">
        <p>Автор: <input type="text" name="author" size="50">
        <p>Год издания: <input type="text" name="pubyear" size="4">
        <p>Цена: <input type="text" name="price" size="6"> руб.
        <p><input type="submit" value="Добавить">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

*db.inc.php*:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
define ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define ('DB_LOGIN', 'root');
define ('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define ('DB_NAME', 'eshop');
define ('ORDERS_LOG', 'orders.log');
// Корзина покупателя
$basket = array();
//Кол-во товаров в корзине покупателя
$count = 0;
$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_LOGIN, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die(mysqli_connect_error());
```

*lib.inc.php*:

```
<?php
function clearInt($data){
    return abs((int)$data);
}

function clearStr($data){
    global $link;
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($link, trim(strip_tags($data)));
}

function addItemToCatalog($title, $author, $pubyear, $price){
    global $link;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO catalog (title, author, pubyear, price)
                   VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
    if(!$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql))
        return false;
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssii", $title, $author, $pubyear, $price);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    return true;
}
```

*save2cat.php*:

```
<?php
    // подключение библиотек
    require "secure/session.inc.php";
    require "../inc/lib.inc.php";
    require "../inc/db.inc.php";

    $author = clearStr($POST['author']);
    $title = clearStr($POST['title']);
    $pubyear = clearInt($POST['pubyear']);
    $price = clearInt($POST['price']);

    if(!addItemToCatalog($title, $author, $pubyear, $price)){
        echo 'Произошла ошибка при добавлении товара';
    }else{
        header('Location: add2cat.php');
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Скорее всего кавычки забыл вокруг строк.

Comment: @Vesper
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) - тут ?

Comment: @Вадим нет, строка с prepared statement выглядит нормальной.

Comment: Почитал немного - нет, говорят нельзя кавычки тут ставить. Тогда не знаю, вроде на первый взгляд ошибок в коде нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильное название массива - не `$POST`, а `$_POST`.

Comment: Как я мог допустить такую ошибку ... 
Спасибо тебе большое !

Answer (score 0):

пользовательская функция clearStr экранирует строку, если прилетает имя O'Neill например, то в базу оно полетит со слешем т.е.: O\'Neill т.к. отправка происходит через подготовленный запрос. Но экранирующий слеш уберётся (будет уместен) при отправке через mysqli_query()